# Compare two dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have records in mysql database and every record has expired date 
so I want to select expired records from my database 
this is the contents of my table:

```
+-------------+-------------+----------------------+
| username    | attribute   | value                |
+-------------+-------------+----------------------+
| ali         | Expiration  | 22 Jan 2018 01:01:30 |
| jon         | Expiration  | 10 Jan 2018 02:02:55 |
| goerge      | Expiration  | 22 Feb 2018 12:03    |    
+-------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

As you can see I have 2 Expired Accounts 
and when I trying to select these expired Records I have `NULL` results.

This is my Query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM radcheck
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(e.value, '%d %M %y'), '%d %M %y')
  <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d %M %y');
```

but the query result show this records

```
+-------------+-------------+----------------------+
| username    | attribute   | value                |
+-------------+-------------+----------------------+
| ali         | Expiration  | 22 Jan 2018 01:01:30 |
| jon         | Expiration  | 10 Jan 2018 02:02:55 |
| goerge      | Expiration  | 22 Feb 2018 12:03    |
+-------------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Even if the second record (jon) is not expired yet.
Where is the mistake?

Comment: which data type is the column value????

Comment: "value" is a poor column name.'

Comment: the datatype of value is varchar 200

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the string in a proper date  and get the date part

```
select * from radcheck 
where  date(STR_TO_DATE(e.value, '%d %b %y %T'))  <= curdate()
```

Comment: Nice use of `%T` for `hh:mm:ss` time...didn't know about this +1.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your data structure so dates are stored as dates.  In a key-value store, you should use the standard date/time formats, so they are readily converted.

In any case, you should be doing the comparison using *dates* not *strings*:

```
select *
from radcheck
where str_to_date(e.value, '%d %M %y') <= curdate();
```

Note that this uses `curdate()` rather than `now()`.  I doubt the current time is something that you need to consider.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `STR_TO_DATE` with the complete format string:

```
SELECT *
FROM radcheck
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(value, '%d %b %y %h:%i:%s') <= CURDATE();
```

But the best long term solution is to not store your dates as text.  Instead, use a date type column for date information.

### Demo